# Spring Boot enable http requests logging (access logs)

Tags: java, http, tomcat, logging, spring-boot

How to enable access logs in an embedded **tomcat** server provided by **spring boot**? I've tried this in `application.properties` but it doesn't create file, neither logs to console.

```
server.tomcat.access-log-enabled=true
server.tomcat.access-log-pattern=%a asdasd
logging.file=/home/mati/mylog.log
```

Comment: I assume you meant "application.properties"? The spelling error in the file name is the only obvious error I can see. Note that the `logging.file` has no effect on the tomcat access log though (although the file ought to be created if you are using a "normal" project setup). Normally the Tomcat valve creates logs in "./logs" (i.e. relative to user.dir).

Comment: Yes, that was my misspell, but in my project it is correct. I know that Spring reads it correctly, because `server.port=9900` works properly. I can't see directory specified by you :(

Comment: Can you share your project?

Comment: Unfortunately no, it is project in my job... maybe there is something in configuration or in pom.xml needed for this to works?

Comment: Works for me. Maybe you can create a simple project that doesn't behave the way you expect and post it in github? If it helps, here's an example of an app that uses the access log successfully: https://github.com/spring-io/sagan/tree/master/sagan-site.

Comment: I have found solution in this repo. It isn't `server.tomcat.access-log-enabled` but `server.tomcat.accessLogEnabled`(in reference it is as dash separated [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#appendix)) . Thank you verry much! If you write this as an answer I can check it as a correct answer :)

Comment: The form of the flag in your properties file makes no different (hyphens or camel case work equally well).

Comment: At the time I have written this questions, hyphens just didn't work. I'm glad to hear that now it works.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try

```
server.tomcat.accessLogEnabled=true
server.tomcat.accessLogPattern=%a asdasd
```

and look in `/tmp/tomcat.<random>.<port>/logs` for the output files. Set  `server.tomcat.basedir` property to change the directory.

Comment: Under Windows, Tomcat creates the log files under `%TEMP%\tomcat.<randomID>.<portnumber>\logs` instead. It's *not* relative to user.dir

Comment: I think that's true on all platforms (unless you set `server.tomact.basedir` explicitly), but it probably wasn't when this answer was first created.

Comment: For Spring boot recent versions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62002598/8718377

Answer (score 44):

Here it goes a way to have them displayed in console or whatever file you choose. Declare Tomcat's [`RequestDumperFilter`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Request_Dumper_Filter) in any `@Configuration` class:

```
@Bean
public FilterRegistrationBean requestDumperFilter() {
    FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
    Filter requestDumperFilter = new RequestDumperFilter();
    registration.setFilter(requestDumperFilter);
    registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
    return registration;
}
```

And that's the output:

```
http-nio-8765-exec-1 START TIME        =30-may-2016 12:45:41
http-nio-8765-exec-1         requestURI=/info
http-nio-8765-exec-1           authType=null
http-nio-8765-exec-1  characterEncoding=UTF-8
http-nio-8765-exec-1      contentLength=-1
http-nio-8765-exec-1        contentType=null
http-nio-8765-exec-1        contextPath=
http-nio-8765-exec-1             cookie=JSESSIONID=E7259F5F9ED6B04CBE5A294C5F8CA5C6
http-nio-8765-exec-1             header=host=mies-057:8765
http-nio-8765-exec-1             header=connection=keep-alive
http-nio-8765-exec-1             header=accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
http-nio-8765-exec-1             header=upgrade-insecure-requests=1
http-nio-8765-exec-1             header=user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36
http-nio-8765-exec-1             header=referer=http://mies-057:1111/
http-nio-8765-exec-1             header=accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, sdch
http-nio-8765-exec-1             header=accept-language=es-ES,es;q=0.8
http-nio-8765-exec-1             header=cookie=JSESSIONID=E7259F5F9ED6B04CBE5A294C5F8CA5C6
http-nio-8765-exec-1             locale=es_ES
http-nio-8765-exec-1             method=GET
http-nio-8765-exec-1           pathInfo=null
http-nio-8765-exec-1           protocol=HTTP/1.1
http-nio-8765-exec-1        queryString=null
http-nio-8765-exec-1         remoteAddr=192.168.56.1
http-nio-8765-exec-1         remoteHost=192.168.56.1
http-nio-8765-exec-1         remoteUser=null
http-nio-8765-exec-1 requestedSessionId=E7259F5F9ED6B04CBE5A294C5F8CA5C6
http-nio-8765-exec-1             scheme=http
http-nio-8765-exec-1         serverName=mies-057
http-nio-8765-exec-1         serverPort=8765
http-nio-8765-exec-1        servletPath=/info
http-nio-8765-exec-1           isSecure=false
http-nio-8765-exec-1 ------------------=--------------------------------------------
http-nio-8765-exec-1 ------------------=--------------------------------------------
http-nio-8765-exec-1           authType=null
http-nio-8765-exec-1        contentType=application/json;charset=UTF-8
http-nio-8765-exec-1             header=Strict-Transport-Security=max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
http-nio-8765-exec-1             header=X-Application-Context=EDGE:8765
http-nio-8765-exec-1             header=Content-Type=application/json;charset=UTF-8
http-nio-8765-exec-1             header=Transfer-Encoding=chunked
http-nio-8765-exec-1             header=Date=Mon, 30 May 2016 10:45:41 GMT
http-nio-8765-exec-1             status=200
http-nio-8765-exec-1 END TIME          =30-may-2016 12:45:41
http-nio-8765-exec-1 ===============================================================
```

Then manage it as any standard Spring Boot log.

Answer (score 20):

In Spring Boot 1.5.1 the [properties mentioned by Dave Syer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23333789/179630) no longer works, instead they're renamed into:

```
server.tomcat.basedir=target/tomcat-logs
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.pattern=%t %a "%r" %s (%D ms)
```

Using the configuration above, if running the project via its root directory the log will be available at target/tomcat-logs/log/access_log.*

Answer (score 14):

With Spring Boot **2.X**, if you want to manage **Access logs**, add these lines to your `application.yml` file:

```
server:
  tomcat:
    basedir: /home/tmp
    accesslog:
      enabled: true
```

It will create a folder named `logs` in the basedir you defined (`/home/tmp` here) containing the access log files.

If you want to have access logs in the console do like that:

```
server:
  tomcat:
    accesslog:
      enabled: true
      directory: /dev
      prefix: stdout
      buffered: false
      suffix:
      file-date-format:
```

It will rediect logs to **/dev/stdout**

More informations: https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/how-to-configure-access-log-entries-for-a-spring-boot-app?language=en_US

Comment: That's a neat trick, but it only works on *nix machines. Notably it does not work when running in Eclipse on Windows, but does work in Docker Compose on Windows (which uses WSL).

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Spring Boot app, and would like to enable http logging to `stdout`, as might be useful in a containerised application, without modifying and code or config files you can add the following environment variables

```
server.tomcat.accesslog.enabled=true
server.tomcat.accesslog.directory=/dev
server.tomcat.accesslog.prefix=stdout
server.tomcat.accesslog.suffix=
server.tomcat.accesslog.file-date-format=
```

Note `suffix` and `file-date-format` should be set to nothing

Then restart your app and you should get logging