# Track all requests in a spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, interceptor

We have used spring boot to write RESTFul web services. There are tons of web services in our application. And the new requirement is here now. My boss asked me to track each service request.
For example : If a login service is invoked, it has to be tracked with count, response status and few more details. Is there a way to that. Something like interceptor which will be invoked after the service is processed and just before the response is served.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the right tool for you is Spring Boot Actuator, especially the /metrics url which tracks requests (and response codes) of every endpoints of your application (among other things) :

https://spring.io/guides/gs/actuator-service/

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am going with different approach of parsing the access logs. Need to finalize the better approach

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot supports servlet filters and allows you to register them the same way you would any @Component.(By having the class annotated with @Component and placing it in a package where Spring Boot will auto-configure the class)

Use the (ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) objects to retrieve the data you require.

```
package application.basepackage.maybeafilterspecificpackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.FilterConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SimpleLoggingFilter implements Filter {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SimpleLoggingFilter .class);

    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        String url = request.getServletPath();
        logger.info(url + " - " + request.getMethod());
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
        logger.info(url + " - " + response.getStatus());
    }

    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {}

    public void destroy() {}

}
```

I created a @RequestMapping mapped to /test where it simply returns a String below I clean up my logs to be more readable.

This first time I had the method throw an exception

```
/test - GET
/test - 500
/favicon.ico - GET
/favicon.ico - 200
```

Then i fixed it to simply return a string

```
/test - GET
/test - 200
/favicon.ico - GET
/favicon.ico - 200
```

You spoke as though you need a little more power over your logs but if you are using embedded Tomcat then a more simple alternative is.

> [Spring Boot enable http requests logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325389/spring-boot-enable-http-requests-logging)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am going with different approach of parsing the access logs. Need to finalize the better approach