# How to enable undertow log in appication.properties in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, logging, undertow, spring-boot-maven-plugin

How to enable http server logs in an embedded tomcat server provided by spring boot in **undertow**? I've tried this in application.properties but it doesn't create file, neither logs to console

I am looking for something similar like this 
[Spring Boot enable http requests logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23325389/spring-boot-enable-http-requests-logging)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
server.undertow.accesslog.enabled=true
server.undertow.accesslog.pattern=%t %a "%r" %s (%D ms)
```

add this code in application.properties