# docker service logs <service-name> & docker logs <image-name> not printing logs

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have 2 nodes, 1 manager and 1 worker. Worker has around 15 spring boot services. All the services seem to be running fine when we use the UI to test the application. However when I am trying to check the logs using the docker service logs  nothing is printed. When I ssh into the worker and try to check logs for individual images the logs are not printed. However when I ssh into the running container I can see a log folder with the generated logs.

This was working a couple of days back. We just redeployed some images and had to scale images from 1 to 0 and back to 1 instances. Not sure why the logs are not printed? Any hints on how we can debug or fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The command `docker logs <container>` only outputs STDOUT and STDERR. You need to configure your logs to push to one of these. Read more about it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36790613/10632970

Comment: But, It was printing logs till last friday with whatever configuration we have and nothing related to logging was changed. The services are spring boot services with logback and sl4j configuration.

Comment: can you share your logging config? it is not uncommon for people to modify containers and never update configs :)